# Converting list of strings with decimals into datetime

Tags: python, string, datetime, matplotlib, strptime

I have the following list of strings that looks like this

```
dates_list = ['7.0:2.0', '6.0:32.0', '6.0:16.0', '6.0:16.0', '6.0:17.0', '6.0:2.0', '6.0:1.0']
```

I want to plot this into a graph but I need to convert into date time of minutes and seconds (%M:%S)

I tried using `strptime`

```
for i in dates_list:
        datetime_object = datetime.strptime(i,'%M:%S')
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '7.0:2.0' does not match format '%M:%S'
```

Is there a way to handle floats or do I have to convert the strings to int and remove the decimals?

Comment: I can't see the error. Could you paste it correctly?

Comment: @IspanCristi fixed error message

Comment: What return are you looking for?

Comment: to convert it into a datetime instead of string of MM:SS. I want to be able to plot this in matplotlib but I cant when its in string format like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will allow you to introduce any decimal:

```
from datetime import datetime

for i in dates_list:
  time_list = i.split(':')
  minute_decimal = time_list[0].split('.')[1]
  second_decimal = time_list[1].split('.')[1]
  datetime_object = datetime.strptime(i,'%M.{0}:%S.{1}'.format(minute_decimal,second_decimal)).time()
```

Comment: Thank you this answer was most comprehensive for my dataset and was able to format all different types of decimal/decimal lengths

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to correctly specify the format

```
import datetime as dt
dates_list = ['7.0:2.0', '6.0:32.0', '6.0:16.0', '6.0:16.0', '6.0:17.0', '6.0:2.0', '6.0:1.0']
for i in dates_list:
        datetime_object = dt.datetime.strptime(i,'%M.0:%S.0').time()
        print(datetime_object)
```

Comment: This will return the complate date. Adding by default year, month and day (1900-01-01), and I'm not sure that's what he wants.

Comment: Hi thanks @Ispan, I have added the time() method at the end. Answer Updated, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Another question: The value after the point, will always be a zero?

Comment: correct, that's what the user has in the list

Comment: Hi what if in case there are values that contain ```2.0:1.4210854715202004e-14```?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with pd.to_datetime(). However, it would add unnecessary date information which you can then remove with strftime:

```
[x.strftime("%M:%S") for x in pd.to_datetime(dates_list,format='%M.0:%S.0')]
```

Returning:

```
['07:02', '06:32', '06:16', '06:16', '06:17', '06:02', '06:01']
```